# Pandas reindex subset of rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'Country': ['USA','USA','AUS','AUS','AUS','UK','UK'],
    'poulation_k':[200,250,150,120,350,800,600,],
    }
           
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

[image]

I would like to sort the rows by poulation where `Country = AUS` but maintaining their order in the overall dataframe:

So my expected output will be:

[image]

I would also like to do it by the other countries however i would like to do it on a manual basis - i.e i would like the function to specify the `Country` name. Any help would be fantastic! Thanks

> UPDATE:

Edit, i negleted to put in that my dataframes consist of other columns as well. so the example should be:

```
import pandas as pd
#Create DF
d = { 
     'Country': ['USA','USA','AUS','AUS','AUS','UK','UK'],
    'poulation_k':[200,250,150,120,350,800,600,],
    }
           
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['Test'] = df.poulation_k.astype(str) + df.Country
df
```

[image]

With the expected output of the function to sort `AUS` being:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def func(country):
    sub_df = df[df['Country']==country] 

    idx_i = sub_df.index
    idx_f = sub_df.sort_values('poulation_k', ascending=False).index

    return df.rename(dict(zip(idx_f, idx_i))).sort_index()
    
func('AUS')
```

[image]

My solution modifies the index so it will work no matter how many columns you have in your dataframe.

Comment: thanks Raymond, is there a way this could be put into a function, similar to the answer from Mayank?

Comment: done that for you. it's not hard to change it, right :) ?

Comment: jsut looking at, no it does not look hard! thats something ive learnt today haha! thank you somuch

Comment: good to hear :).

Comment: have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

As you only reorder one column, you can do it simply:

```
df.loc[df['Country'] == 'AUS', 'poulation_k'] = np.sort(
    df.loc[df['Country'] == 'AUS', 'poulation_k'].values)
```

It gives as expected:

```
  Country  poulation_k
0     USA          200
1     USA          250
2     AUS          120
3     AUS          150
4     AUS          350
5      UK          800
6      UK          600
```